# How can I iterate over a 2D vector in functional style?

Tags: loops, vector, functional-programming, iterator, rust

The following doesn't work, unfortunately:

```
let vecs: Vec<Vec<i32>> = get_vectors();

let result = vecs
    .iter()
    .iter()
    .do_something()
    .do_something_else() // etc
```

Compiles with the error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `iter` found for type`std::slice::Iter<'_, std::vec::Vec<i32>>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:49:10
   |
49 |         .iter()
   |
```

I can avoid it with

```
for row in vecs.iter() {
    for column in row.iter() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

I'd really prefer the `.iter()` method. How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`flatten`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flatten):

```
fn main() {
    let v = vec![vec![1, 2], vec![3, 4], vec![5, 6]];

    for i in v.iter().flatten() {
        println!("{}", i); // 1 2 3 4 5 6
    }
}
```

`flatten` transforms nested iterators into one iterator.

Comment: @Yee You're welcome. Don't hesitate to read the whole documentation of iterator (and slice), you'll see a ton of usefull methods ;)